# Правильно расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: запятые

### Но, мне кажется, смысла нет

По идее, вводное предложение должно быть обособлено, но похожее сочетание сочинительного союза с данной конструкцией кажется весьма странным

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вторая запятая обязательна, а первая опциональна. Если автор фразы делает акцент на собственное мнение относительно смысла, то будет `«Но мне кажется, смысла нет»`. Если нужно передать лишь ощущение отсутствия смысла, то используется вводное сочетание, и тогда первая запятая нужна: `«Но, мне кажется, смысла нет»`.

Необходимость обособления можно часто проверить так: ставим запятую, если можем опустить обособленное выражение без существенного ущерба для смысла предолжения: `«Но, мне кажется, смысла нет»` в сущности есть то же, что: `«Но смысла нет»`.

Comment: Согласен. Для полноты картины можно рассмотреть вариант: "но мне, кажется, смысла нет". То есть всем раздали, а мне, похоже, не хватило. (Шутка :)

Comment: Да, точно, вот что значит запятая!

Answer (score 1):

**Эта тема изложена у Розенталя** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

6. Между присоединительным союзом (в начале самостоятельного предложения) и вводным словом (сочетанием) **запятая обычно не ставится,** так как союз тесно примыкает к вводному слову:  Но конечно, всё кончилось благополучно; Но так или иначе, предложенный вариант вполне приемлем;

Иногда (при интонационном выделении вводных слов или предложений, при их включении в текст посредством подчинительного союза) после присоединительного союза **запятая перед вводной конструкцией ставится:** Но, к великой моей досаде, Швабрин… решительно объявил, что песня моя нехороша (И.);

Постановка запятой позволяет разграничить вводное сочетание и независимое предложение в составе бессоюзного сложного предложения. Ср.: **Но, я вижу,** вам это не подходит (вводное предложение). — **Но я вижу,** вам это не подходит (бессоюзное сложное предложение).